# What is Cygwin and how to use it in relation in Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

Hi I am new to android NDK Devlopment.I downloaded Android NDK 4 for windows.I read through the docs.But i am not clear with it.

First thing is that,I want to develop the native file which may be c 0r c++.I think Using Cygwin will come to play.I dont have any idea or how to use cygwin .From the Docs i just read Cygwin is required for Windows platform.Apart from it ,i dont have any knowledge about it.

Not yet started with NDK Concepts.Help Required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cygwin is a way to make Windows support some linux functionality. If you install cygwin on your windows machine you'd be able to run some linux software on windows (you'd have to recompile it especially for cygwin though). You can find it and more information about it [here](http://www.cygwin.com/). There's also a good explanation at the wiki page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

If the Android NDK needs it I suppose the Android NDK needs some linux functionality or tools to work properly. The other option might be to install Linux on a machine and run the Android NDK on there, it might be better since I assume Linux is the native environment for Android NDK development.

Since you're saying that you're a bit unclear about the NDK, you should probably be aware that as far as I understand you can not build a whole Android app using it, you can only develop bits of it, you will still need to develop at least part of the app to run on top of the Dalvik virtual machine, which, as far as I know, means that you'll have to write that bit in Java. In general I think that you should develop Android apps only in Java unless there is a specific reason to build certain parts of it using the NDK.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input.I have other doubt also regarding Eclipse.Is it possible in Eclipse or using Eclipse Plugin to create and  compile the  Native Code.Any Ideas on this

Comment: @Rakesh: Sorry, never used Eclipse much, probably might be worth creating a new question about that.

Answer (score 2):

From wiki:
Cygwin (pronounced /ˈsɪɡwɪn/,[2] SIG-win) is a Unix-like environment and command-line interface for Microsoft Windows. Cygwin provides native integration of Windows-based applications, data, and other system resources with applications, software tools, and data of the Unix-like environment. Thus it is possible to launch Windows applications from the Cygwin environment, as well as to use Cygwin tools and applications within the Windows operating context.
Cygwin consists of two parts: a Dynamic-link library (DLL) as an API compatibility layer providing a substantial part of the POSIX API functionality, and an extensive collection of software tools and applications that provide a Unix-like look and feel.

So, Cygwin is a set of tools which allows you to emulate a unix-like (or linux) environment on your windows machines.

The NDK is the Android Native Development Kit.  It allows you to write parts of your application in native code (C/C++) and integrate them into your application.  Your application still runs under the Dalvik VM but it can load shared objects creating using a cross compiler.  The NDK contains all the necessary tools and build scripts to generate native code binaries.  It's an advanced concept and one you should probably wait on until you fully understand the architecture.

The reason why it requires Cygwin (or some flavor of linux) is because it uses GnuMake and other linux tools such as awk or Nawk.  These tools are not available (or are really hard to use) on windows platforms, hence the need for at least Cygwin (though I would advise you do yourself a favor and just install linux).