# How to use .so files for encrypt decrypt file?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have c program which is encrypt/decrypt file with aes algorithm.
Here it is http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt
I have windows pc so I am using cygwin.

Now I want use this c program and create .so file and this .so file want use in android project.

but I don't know how to create .so file and How to use this .so file with android project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create native C++ library on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147382/how-to-create-native-c-library-on-android)

Comment: it is not clear there. and this is use c library not c++ library.